# conditional in value assignment

Tags: c++

In c++, I want to use conditionals when assigning values, for example:

```
int i = true && 5 || 3;
```

For example, using Lua you can write this:

```
i = true and 5 or 3
```

I am not sure that this is possible

Here is something that I tried:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

void main()
{
    int test = (true && 5) || 1;
    int test2 = (false && 6) || 2;

    std::cout << "Test: " << test << std::endl << "Test2: " << test2 << std::endl;
    for(;;);
}
```

Comment: What behaviour are you expecting here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ isn't Lua.

In Lua, `true and 5` expression results in `5`. That's simply how Lua works with boolean expressions.

And that's not how C++ works with boolean expressions. In C++, a boolean expression results in a boolean *value*. That is, either `true` or `false`.

If you want to select between two values based on a condition, we have an operator for that:

```
int i = true ? 5 : 3;
```

If the condition is true, you get the value before the `:`. If it's false, you get the value after the `:`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're looking for `int test = true ? 5 : 1;`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a conditional expression:

```
  int i = true ? 2 : 5;
```

In this case `i` will be 2.

Answer (score 0):

If we really wanted to, as of c++11 (which gives us the `and` and `or` keywords as a synonyms for `&&` and `||`), we could almost strong-arm the c++ compiler into compliance, and get it to compile this:

```
int x = when_true(b) and 5 or 6;
```

In order to do this we would need to provide some scaffolding:

```
#include <iostream>

struct maybe_int {
    bool cond;
    int x;

    operator int() const { return x; }
};

int operator || (const maybe_int& l, int r) {
    if (l.cond) return l.x;
    return r;
}

struct when_true {
    when_true(bool condition)
    : _cond(condition)
    {}

    auto operator&&(int x) const {
        return maybe_int { _cond, x };
    }

    bool _cond;

};


int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    auto b = false;
    int x = when_true(b) and 5 or 6;
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My suggestion would be that you don't try this kind of thing at work.